# How to set project specific JRE in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have openjdk 11 as my workspace default JRE and I want to change project oa-ejb's JRE to jdk1.8.

This is what I did:
[image: Before I change]

After I click "Apply and close", return to Edit library window:
[image: After I click "Apply and close", return to Edit library window]

I want to change 1 project's JRE but it change my default JRE! How can I do?

Comment: Your first screen shot shows where you did the mistake: Don't press the `Installed JREs...` button, instead just select `Alternate JRE` and select the JRE you want from the then enabled drop down menu.

Comment: @Robert Yes, please add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! I voted Robert's comment as a useful comment. But I don't know how to add it as an answer.